# Emberjs and Validation

Tags: ember.js

How are people handling client side validation and ember?

Is there anything out of the box or a plugin that handles validation or are people just rolling their own?

Comment: Are you just having a validation, or are you on a strong MVC with controller and Model backing your view? Can you put up a sample scenario?

Comment: Is there anything that hooks into rails validation messages?

Comment: In fact this is `ActiveModel::Validations` (which is not strongly needed in Rails). Anyway I'm currently developping this kind of validation for Ember. but this is still in development: http://goo.gl/KD9Un

Comment: There is a project called [Flame](https://github.com/flamejs/flame.js), but it's not 100%, and you have the disadvantage of not being able to use Ember Views, you'd have to replace all your views with Flame Views. You can check some validations examples [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NeqX4/)

Comment: Sounds like a good open-source start up project to me.

Answer (score 17):

https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations might be useful. It also hooks up to [Ember-easy-form](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ember/2013/02/21/ember-easy-form.html)

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap you should also consider [ember-forms](https://github.com/ember-addons/ember-forms) with ember-validations.

Comment: Yes, this is the common solution to client side validation now with Ember. It's super simple and integrates nicely with [ember-easyForm](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easyForm) & both are made by Dockyard.

Answer (score 14):

I would extend Ember.TextField (or whatever input type your validating) and use classBinding with a computed property. Here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/caligoanimus/7UNRd/

template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{view App.AlphaNumField
        placeholder="alpha-numeric data only"
        valueBinding="App.alphaNumInput"}}
</script>
```

application:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    AlphaNumField:  Ember.TextField.extend({
        isValid: function() {
            return /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(this.get('value'));
        }.property('value'),
        classNameBindings: 'isValid:valid:invalid'
    })
});
```

Comment: Maybe we should extend ember itself to have these default bindings? not an app goes by that doesn't need solid client side validations.

Comment: As an update - Dockyard now has ember-validations which I am using and prefer to others.

Answer (score 4):

Another fully supported option and very logical if you are using bootstrap is to use [bootstrap-validation plugin](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator). In ember (ember-cli) this should be installed using bower:

```
bower install --save bootstrap-validation
```

then in ember-cli-build you must import dependencies:

```
//bootstrap-validator
  app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.js');
  app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.min.js');
```

This solution allows you to validate at html level, letting bootstrap do the 'dirty' job. For standard validations this will do the job simple and effortless.

Answer (score 3):

I have been handling it in a very similar way to @caligoanimus, but validating on the focus out of the text box and appending an error message.

code:

```
App.TextFieldEmpty = Ember.TextField.extend({
   focusOut: function() {
      var valid = this.get('value') ? valid = true : valid = false;
      this.$().next(".err").remove();

      if(!valid){
        this.$().addClass("invalid").after("<span class='err'>This field is required</span>");
      } else {
        this.$().removeClass("invalid")
      }
   }
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
   {{view App.TextFieldEmpty}}
</script>
```

JSBIN:

http://jsbin.com/uriroYO/6/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3):

I've had a lot of success with [jQuery Validate:](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'my-form-template',
    didInsertElement: function(){
        $("#myForm").validate({
            rules:{
                fname:{
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50,
                },
                lname:{
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50,
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    maxlength: 200,
                },
            },
            messages: {
                email: { 
                    email: "Enter a valid email address.",
                },
            },
        });
    }
});
```

Just using the Ember input helper, it's made my form validation very clean. You can take your jQuery Validate script and place it in a .js file as a function and just call that on didInsertElement.

jQuery Validate adds error messages below your fields with the message relating to the rule, and also allows you to trigger validation from any of your actions or events through the .valid() method.

Answer (score 2):

We have created our own text fields which raise validation errors on focus out, and other events and other text fields extend them:

```
App.PhoneNumberField = App.TextField.extend({
    validate: function(value) {
        var self = this.$('input');
        var id = self.attr("id");
        var e164PhoneNumber = formatE164("AU",value);
        var valid = true;
        if(self.val().trim().length == 0 ){
            valid = true;
        }else{
            valid = isValidNumber(e164PhoneNumber);
        }
        if (!valid) {
            self.trigger(Storm.invalidInputEvent(id));
            this.setErrorMessage("error","Phone Number does not look right");
        }else {
            self.trigger(Storm.validInputEvent(id));
            this.clearMessages();
        }
    },

    keyUp: function(evt) {
        if(evt.keyCode >= 37 && evt.keyCode <=40)
        {
          return;
        }
        var textValue = this.$("input").val();
        var input = this.$().find('input');
        var formattedNumber = this.formatInput(textValue);
        input.val(formattedNumber);
        this.set('data',formattedNumber);
    },

    value: function() {
        var phoneNumber = this.get('data');
        if (phoneNumber) {
            return phoneNumber;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }.property('data'),

    data: null,

    placeholder: function() {
        return "";
    }.property('placeholder'),

    formatInput: function(textValue){
        var formattedPhoneNumber = formatLocal("AU",textValue);
        return formattedPhoneNumber;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a model / persistance layer which uses a conventional "errors" object to save validation errors on the model.

Since Ember shines when it comes to observing changes, I would observe the changing errors object to determine whether or not should there be shown a validation message.

In my current setup I'm using [Tower.js](http://towerjs.org/) as framework, because it uses Ember as the View layer, and has a strong model / persistance layer. This layer allows me to define validations on model level. Each time I try to persist a model, it is validated and an error is thrown. In my views, this error aborts the "ideal" path and does not keep executing the workflow, instead it renders the validation errors in the template.